# Use More than One Sequelize.fn?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I see many examples such as:

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: [[sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('hats')), 'no_hats']]
});
```

But say you need to use another function in addition to 'COUNT' e.g. `sequelize.fn('LOWERCASE'...` or `sequelize.fn('UNIQUE'...`. Is there a way to use more than one `sequelize.fn` at a time?

**UPDATE**

I'm looking for a syntax that would let me use two functions in one `findAll()`... possibly something along the lines of:

```
Model.findAll({
  attributes: [[sequelize.fn(['LOWERCASE','UNIQUE'], sequelize.col('hats'))]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do like this

```
Model.findAll({
   attributes: [
            [sequelize.fn('COUNT', sequelize.col('hats')), 'no_hats'],
            [sequelize.fn('LOWERCASE', sequelize.col('name')), 'name'],
            [Sequelize.literal('COUNT(DISTINCT(hats))'), 'no_hats']
        ]
});
```

Comment: But what if I want to use, say, UNIQUE and LOWERCASE on the same column -- e.g. `Model.findAll({
  attributes: [[sequelize.fn(['COUNT', 'UNIQUE], sequelize.col('hats')), 'no_hats']]
});` ?

Comment: For unique count, You can use like this  [ [ Sequelize.literal('COUNT(DISTINCT(hats))'), 'no_hats' ] ]